# Is it considered a best practice to create question titles in the form of a question?

Tags: discussion

In the world of scrum/agile, it's considered good form on some scrum teams to create story titles using the "As xxx, I want to yyy" format.

Is there a similar best practice / recommended approach for Stack Overflow questions?  Should question titles be posed in the form of a question, or is it better to title a question with a statement or phrase indicating the subject matter?  For example, I could title a question about how to escape a double quote in a Velocity Template in two ways:

```
Title A: Escaping double quotes in Velocity templates
```

or

```
Title B: How do I escape a double quote in a Velocity template?
```

Certainly for some, this is a matter of preference.  But it would be interesting to see supporting facts - such as numbers of questions that are answered, number of views, etc of each type (question vs phrase).  If there's a clear difference, that might yield an answer as to which is more effective.

Comment: Not asking a question in the title is a strong selector for questions that completely fail to actually ask a question in the body.  Or drone on for a while, asking multiple questions.  Puts them on the wrong path, I guess.

Comment: See also [Should question titles be phrased as questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19999) on MSE.

Comment: @DavidG: is your query accessible to others?  I got a 'not found' page with a picture of E F Codd on it.

Comment: I'm not a web search specialist, but I'd expect that you can increase the chance to find a post titled as question for those searching for *how to*, or *how do I do*. But it's just my expectation, I don't know if that works so in real...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No idea why that link is 404ing, very odd. Anyway, here is a better link... http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/322569

Answer (score 14):

It is irrelevant whether the question title is grammatically phrased as a question or as a statement.  Neither is a problem.  All that matters is whether or not is able to accurately and concisely summarize the core question being asked.

Comment: It would be interesting to see some kind of comparison between questions whose titles contain question marks as opposed to questions without, and what average views/votes/answers they get.

Comment: I would suspect that titles not in the form of a question are generally worse. I think it leads to bad titles like "java problem with streams".

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Does "How do I use streams in Java?" sound any better? If a person doesn't take the time to figure out a good summary, I'm not convinced that asking them to phrase it as a question is going to make them do so.

Comment: @jpmc26 no, I'm not saying its a perfect system, Im just saying based on my intuition I think it will lead to better question titles overall.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg My intuition is that  "check the box" type rules are generally ineffective at improving actual quality.

Comment: @jpmc26 It sounded like David was saying that the people that write good titles will phrase them as a question, but that the title isn't good *because* they phrased it as a question, rather those people that take the time to write good titles are going to prefer to write their titles as questions.  The causation is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered a best practice to create question titles in the form of a question?

I hadn't thought about it in the past, but we should encourage titles to be phrased as questions. After all, SO is a Q/A platform.

When I looked at [my list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu?tab=questions), I noticed that about 50% of the titles are phrased as questions. When I ask a question next time, I'll make an attempt to make the title a question.

Comment: The fact that SO is a Q/A platform doesn't necessitate that titles be grammatically phrased as questions.  As long as it's clear what is actually being asked when looking at the post as a whole it's fine.

Comment: @Servy, of course. I am not saying we mandate that the titles be phrased as questions. I think when a poster takes the time to phrase the title as a question, it helps bring clarity to their thinking. I imagine that brings clarity to the overall question as well.